# Error whilst trying to use the .difference() function in Python Jupyter

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests

**Context**

I am currently going through a course on webscraping. Upon getting to the module on scraping javascript, a function `set_1.difference(set_2)` was used to distinguish the old variables from the newly created variables. But when I did it, it brought up this error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'difference'`

I searched online and stumbled on this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/). But running the example on their own website brought up an error

**Problem**

Any reason why this is not working? I want to print the newly generated javascript links. Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
session = AsyncHTMLSession()

r = await session.get('https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/datasets/economicactivityfasterindicatorsuk')
r.status_code
 

divs = r.html.find('div')
downloads = r.html.find('a')
urls = r.html.absolute_links
    
# Now need to render the javascript. Downloads chromium the first time we use it,
# It is a browser that has no GUI
await r.html.arender()
    
new_divs = r.html.find('div')
new_downloads = r.html.find('a')
new_urls = r.html.absolute_links
    
# Get only the newly created html
new_downloads.difference(downloads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what the "r" object is, so can't verify your code but `difference` is a method of sets, not lists.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference

This should do the trick: `set(new_downloads).difference(downloads)`